# If $a(\cos x-1)+b^2=\cos(ax+b^2)-1$ hold true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, Then $(a,b)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Number of positive integer ordered pair $(a,b)$ for which the equation
>
> $a(\cos x-1)+b^2=\cos(ax+b^2)-1$ hold true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write above equation as $a(\cos x-1)+b^2+1 = \cos(ax+b^2)$

Now Using $\cos x\leq 1\Rightarrow a(\cos x-1)+b^2+1 \leq b^2+1$

and $-1 \leq \cos (ax+b^2)\leq 1$

Now How can I solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$x=0$ gives $\cos(b^2)=b^2+1$. However $b^2+1\geq 1 \geq \cos(x)$, with equality only if $b=0$.

Since your question requires positive integers, we're technically done.

However, I shall proceed to find all integers $a$ for which it holds.
Now we get $a(\cos(x)-1)=\cos(ax)-1$. $x=\frac12 \pi$ gives $-a=\cos(a\frac12 \pi)-1$.

But $a$ is an integer, so $\cos(a\frac12 \pi)$ is -1,0 or 1. so $-a=-1$, $-a=-2$ or $-a=0$, so $a=0$, $a=1$ or $a=2$. $a=0$ and $a=1$ indeed work.

For $a=2$ let $x=\pi$ and we get $2\cdot(-2)=\cos(2\pi)-1=0$, which is not true.

One can also prove that this are in fact all real solutions.

---

**Conclusion:** For positive integers $(a,b)$ there exists no such pair.

In the real numbers, the only pairs are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure that $a=2$ works, but the other two do.

Comment: @user84413 Indeed, that was sloppy.